# Output of command file, when file is INI file

Tags: file-command

I'm trying to understand the output of the `file` command when used on an INI-file. I create a file like this ("DOS" line endings are crucial, otherwise it is recognized as an ascii text file)

```
;Trying to create an example
[FOO]
Order=First

[BAR]
Order=Second

[BAZ]
Order=Third
```

`test.ini: Generic INItialization configuration [BAR]\015`

I have tried this on Arch on wsl and ArchLinux, both resulting in the same output.

The output of `strings /usr/share/file/misc/magic.mgc | grep` tells me something is supposed to be shown, because there is this format string: `INItialization Generic INItialization configuration [%-.40s`.

I just can't figure out all of what `file` tries to tell me. Why BAR, why not FOO or BAZ?  What is the `\015` part telling me?

Comment: It's telling you that it has identified the file as an INI file. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: The `\015` probably indicates a _Carriage Return_ character following the `[text]` string in the file, because your INI-file is from a DOS/Windows environment where a line terminator is the pair _Carriage Return_ and _Line Feed_, contrary to the Linux line terminator which is only _Line Feed_

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, thank you for the pointer, of course it is. Octal 015 is decimal 13, which of course is CR.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I had a hard time wording my question, it was not as clear as it could be, I apologize. For every other file type I tried `file` returned a "static" result. For ini-files there seems to be a dynamic component, or so I gather from the message file. What I cannot wrap my head around is what is selected for the dynamic part of the format string. To me it seems to be random, but usually these things aren't.

Comment: @johnny It's hard for us to tell without you showing examples of the INI files in question.

Comment: @Kusalananda The original ini-files aren't mine to share and I failed in creating an example. Now I succeeded when I realized that line endings were important.